# Deduce Distinct Digits of the Given Fibonacci Sequence- Detail all Steps

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, knowledge, number-sequence, no-computers

$DEPUS$

$SRST$

$UDQD$

$CTQU$

$DTPR$

$PQR$

$SDE$

$VRR$

$CVV$

$DUU$

$QP$

$TT$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is:

> $D=1,C=2,V=3,R=7,E=0,S=6,Q=8,P=9,T=5,U=4$

Giving:

> $55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946$

Logic:

> The brackets contain the line (from the bottom) used.
>
>  $D=1$ as sum of two 2-digit numbers $\lt200$ (123). $C=2$ by the same argument (234), therefore, because $U+V$ doesn't carry, $V=3$ (345). We have $V+R=E$ next to $V+R=D=1$ (456), so $V+R$ must carry, and $D=E+1$, so $E=0$. Also $V+C+1=S$ (456), so $S=6$. $Q=R+D=7+1=8$ (567), and the second line up tells us $P=Q+1=9$ (123). $P+S=DT$ (678), so $T=5$, giving $U=4$ (123).

Comment: Alternate approach: The first 3-digit numbers all end in a doubled digit? Surely OP wouldn't have used the actual Fibonacci sequence?