# Fibonacci again..Distinct Digits..Detail all your Deductive Steps

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-sequence, no-computers

$ABB$

$CDE$

$GFB$

$DPGB$

$QPFR$

$RDFD$

Comment: Puzzled by downvotes for this..concise..purely logic based..no ambiguities..clear

Comment: You are asking the solver to make a lot of assumptions about what to solve.

Comment: @Uvc The reason (I think) you are getting a lot of downvotes is that you post **a lot** of puzzles, particularly of the kind that don't take any effort at all to create. Case in point: this puzzle is a strict subset of [the puzzle you posted two days ago](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85726/deduce-distinct-digits-of-the-given-fibonacci-sequence-detail-all-steps). One of these puzzles shouldn't exist, and if you had tried to solve both variations before posting, you would have known which is the better one, and posted only that.

Comment: @Uvc, since one can't really take a puzzle back after posting it, I'd like to recommend sleeping on every puzzle, and then trying to solve it again in the morning. This has saved many of my own puzzles from being a disaster. Also, it's not like the internet is going anywhere, and this isn't a "post as much as you can" competition, so waiting until the next day before posting increases puzzle quality without costing much anything. Cheers, and happy puzzling!

Comment: Puzzles need to be self contained. Looking at just what is posted here, there is no explanation whatsoever of what this puzzle is asking for, making it literally *unclear what you’re asking* here. @Bass has given some good advice, and taken together with earlier comments you’ve received about avoiding genre fatigue, I hope this will encourage you to slow things down. Too much of even a good thing isn’t good, and it’s not a race here.

Comment: I completely agree.  You may or may not think I'm biased or whatever, but I will say that I'm finding this posting frequency extremely concerning, as we really should be focusing on promoting quality (and variety!) over quantity.  Many well reputable users here rarely post a puzzle.  Look at, say, puzzles by Deusovi, Alconja, or Paramesis (as well as many great puzzle creators that I regret not having enough space here to list).  They don't post often at all, but all of their puzzles are quite nice - in fact, they all have a *perfect* track record with no negatively received questions, ever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1 - expected solution**

> $$ABB+CDE=GFB\implies E=0\\CDE+GFB<2000\implies D=1\\GFB+DPGB<3000\implies Q=2\\R=D+Q+1=4\,\text{carrying due to}\,P+P=D=1\\1PGB+2PF4=41F1\implies B=(1)1-4=7\\A77+C10=GF7\implies F=7+1=8\\C10+G87=1PG7\implies G=1+8=9\\1P97+2P84=4181\implies P+P=(1)1\implies P=5\\\text{remaining integers are}\,3,6\implies A=3,C=6\\\boxed{A=3,\quad B=7,\quad C=6,\quad D=1,\quad E=0,\quad F=8,\\G=9,\quad P=5,\quad Q=2,\quad R=4.}$$

---

**Solution 2 - uses known Fibonacci list**

Step 1:

> List of three- and four-digit Fibonacci numbers: $144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765$

Step 2:

> Thus we see that $B=7$ since we have $ABB$ and $GFB$. Therefore $A=3$ and $DPGB=1597$.

Step 3:

> Next, since $G=9$, we have that $F=8$. Since $D=1$, we have that $RDFD=4181$ and $QPFR=2584$.

Step 4:

> Finally, $CDE=610$ since $D=1$.

Step 5:

> So $$A=3,\quad B=7,\quad C=6,\quad D=1,\quad E=0,\quad F=8,\\G=9,\quad P=5,\quad Q=2,\quad R=4.$$ These are distinct from $0-9$.

Comment: You cannot just see..every number has to be logically deduced right from step 1

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want me to elaborate, i.e. B=7 since we have ABB and GFB both ending in B and 7 is the only number that does this (377 and 987)?

Comment: No..you cannot take from literature..you have to mathematically deduce every digit through logical reasoning

Comment: It's not literature: I can write out the list of Fibonacci numbers by hand from the definition.

Comment: Then it is not a puzzle..every digit can be mathematically deduced using fib properties

Comment: Exactly. Isn't that the point of the question? Perhaps you can provide a self-answer so that others can see how it's meant to be done

Comment: They have solved previous one..I don’t see why they cannot do this one...let us give time..it is not an even hour yet

Comment: i think Uvc meant it may not be the classic fib seq, but the fib pattern and characteristic?

Comment: No..it is classic fib..I have spent 3 hours to make sure every step flows thro sheer logic...sequence is right..key is to prove it

Comment: Done.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: That is the expected deductive reasoning.in the spirit of the puzzle...although couple of alternate paths exist..leading to the same result